# Performance hit from having unused properties in objects

Tags: typescript, performance

I have three repos, a Typescript Node.js server, Typescript React, and a bunch of class definition in the last one. The main reason for this kind of setup is because I want to share types that are used in both Node.js server and the client, and make it easier to maintain. The first two are not connected, and the rest is connected by using the `"reference"` property in `ts.config`.

In the third repo, there are two types for some of the objects: one contains encrypted data, and one contains data in plaintext (like `Record` and `EncryptedRecord`). This is to make sure the server never receives an unencrypted variant by accident. I originally wanted to add member function like `Record.encrypt()` that returns an encrypted object, and `EncryptedRecord.decrypt()` that returns decrypted object, and I added those in the third repo. The code looks neat.

But then I realised that the server never uses member function `.decrypt()` in an encrypted object, or definitions regarding unencrypted objects (which needs to be included because that is what gets returned in those `.decrypt()` functions), both of which are included in the third repo.

How much performance hit would the server get for importing interfaces and including member function that will never be used? I expect millions of objects with useless member function to be created in the server. I can kind of get around this by separating `.decrypt()` and all decrypted type definitions into the client, but I would have to do something like

```
import decryptRecord from './somewhere';
import decryptUserData from './somwhereelse';
...
const record = decryptRecord(encryptedRecord, cryptoKey);
const userData = decryptUserData(encryptedUserData, cryptoKey);
```

instead of

```
const record = encryptedRecord.decrypt(cryptoKey);
const userData = encryptedUserData.decrypt(cryptoKey);
```

which I want to avoid.

Comment: "*How much performance hit would the server get for importing interfaces and including member function that will never be used?*" unknowable unless you performance test it yourself. But chances are the impact would be *extremely* small. Perhaps even immeasurable or otherwise irrelevant. "*I expect millions of objects with useless member function to be created in the server.*" if you have a class, then the `decrypt` will only exist once in memory for all the million records.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, which answers it. I suppose it should have been something along the lines of whether or not I should include client side code in the shared code, even if it's just to make it cleaner.

Comment: I agree with @VLAZ, you should not experience any performance hit. However memory usage might be increased.